# How to batch render sprites in OpenGL ES (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, batch-file, opengl-es, render, sprite

I have a game that renders a bunch of sprites (several hundred), almost all of which are using the same texture. Currently, I'm calling glDrawArrays(...) for each one, which I recently discovered was very inefficient. After doing some research, I've learned that I need to put all my vertices for every sprite into one big vertex buffer, and call glDrawArrays(...) just once using that. However, when I do so it only draws the first sprite, and the other 200 are blank.

```
blueSpriteVertices[blueBatchNum * 4] = Vertex3DMake(xloc, yloc, zloc);
blueSpriteVertices[blueBatchNum * 4 + 1] = Vertex3DMake(xloc + size, yloc, zloc);
blueSpriteVertices[blueBatchNum * 4 + 2] = Vertex3DMake(xloc, yloc + size, zloc);
blueSpriteVertices[blueBatchNum * 4 + 3] = Vertex3DMake(xloc + size, yloc + size, zloc);
blueBatchNum++;
//^^This block of code^^ is called iteratively, adding data for various sprites
//(around 200) to the vertex array. "xloc", "yloc", etc. are private members of 
//this sprite class


//Draw the whole batch
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);

//This code is actually in the Texture2D class implementation, hence "_name"
//and "coordinates"
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _name);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, blueSpriteVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Comment: This code seems to be your original version drawing each texture with a separate glDrawArrays call, you only have 4 vertices being passed into it...

Comment: The first block of code is repeated around 200 times, adding new xloc and yloc data to the array for each sprite; I cut out a lot of code in between so I guess that's not clear. I'll try to edit it so it'll make more sense.

Comment: Where do you define the `coordinates` array?  How many elements does it have?

Comment: It is defined within the Texture2D class, and has 4 pairs (8 elements total) of GLfloats for the 4 corners of the texture itself. Does this array need to match the vertex buffer in size?

Comment: How do you manage the blueSpriteVertices[] array? You construct it every frame? When some of the sprites are no longer needed, what do you do? You delete some rows?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem by using GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, and handled the triangle strips manually. By doing so I was able to eliminate all the "strips" that it was interpreting *in between* my sprites. Works like a charm now, and the batching definitely improved my game's performance astronomically.

Answer (score 2):

Using (GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP works for me (on Android)

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6 * mSpriteCounter, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (char*) NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The glDrawArrays() last parameter should contain the number of vertices (in your case you have only 4). Also you must have the same number of texture coordinates to match the drawn vertices!

Comment: I tried changing the last parameter of glDrawArrays(), but what it did was draw one huge mess of triangle strips that connected all my sprites together. What I want is a whole bunch of separate sprites, each a combination of two triangles. I'll try changing the texture coordinate array and reply again in a few minutes.

Comment: After changing the texture coordinate array and the last parameter of glDrawArrays(), it still draws the whole mess of triangle strips, except all the strips contain the stretched texture (vs. just a solid color like before). So I guess this was a step in the right direction.

Comment: Then check the coord arrays, to make sure you have them correcly according to the triangle strip coords.